# Remove Passbook's "Add credit or debit card" without adding one

Tags: iphone, wallet

I don't want to use Passbook to pay for anything.  However, I bought a concert ticket online with a credit card, and I was given the option of downloading the ticket to Passbook.  I can see the ticket in Passbook, but I have to pull it up with my finger in order to display the barcode-ey thing that will allow me to get into the show--because the white "Pay with Touch ID using Apple Pay" message fills up the first 2/5 of the screen on my phone.

Is there any way to get rid of the message box without adding a credit/debit card?

I can use the ticket, I guess, but the message box is annoying.

(In case it matters: iPhone 6, iOS 8.4)

Comment: You may find that when you are at the venue, the passbook 'ticket' will automatically pop up ready for use.

Comment: Interesting.  OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tap on the pass, and the "Pay with Touch ID using Apple Pay" message will go away temporarily to give way to fully displaying the pass, card, coupon, or ticket.